# Reachability returning inaccurate status

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, reachability

I have a simple [Reachability](https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability) code that returns if I can connect to a server or not:

```
-(BOOL)checkConnectionForHost:(NSString*)host{
   _checkStatus = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostname:host];
   NetworkStatus networkStatus = [_checkStatus currentReachabilityStatus];
   return networkStatus != NotReachable;
}
```

I tested it by adding stuff like `google.com`, and it works fine. However, if I type in a junk number like `8170319837018`, and call this function, it still return `TRUE`. However, if I add any char to it, like `8170319837018a`, it will return `FALSE`, as it should. Am I calling the wrong method on `Reachability`? Do I have to check if the string is a URL or an IP address?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Reachability has some issues. If You are connected to wifi it will return it's rechable but doesn't actually ping the host. Better way would be to use `NSURLCONNECTION` to ping the server directly

```
+ (BOOL)pingURL:(NSString *)url
{
    NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:1];
    NSURLResponse *response = nil;
    NSError *error = nil;
    [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
    NSLog(@"response %d", [(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response statusCode]);
    if ([(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response statusCode] == 200) {
        return YES;
    }

    return NO;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Will this work with addresses as well? Also, what if I'm trying to ping a non-HTTP port?

Comment: Thanks, but your example only handles HTTP requests/responses. What if I wanted to ping an FTP or SSH protocol? Wouldn't the statusCodes, etc. be different?

Comment: @Carpetfizz , Main purpose of the Rechability is to check whether you have internet connectivity. Once you have that than you can test the SSH or FTP connection.

Comment: @doNotCheckMyBlog, thanks and can I do that with NSURLRequest?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is because the internal reachability flags are long numbers. So when you pass 8170319837018 the [_checkStatus currentReachabilityStatus] must be returning some number which is not equal to NotReachable(0) and that's why it must be returning TRUE. What you can instead do is to check against each type of reachability like below:

```
-(BOOL)checkConnectionForHost:(NSString*)host{
   _checkStatus = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostname:host];
   NetworkStatus networkStatus = [_checkStatus currentReachabilityStatus];
   return (networkStatus == ReachableViaWiFi) || (networkStatus == ReachableViaWWAN);
}
```